# How to verify self-signed certificate in PHP?

Tags: php, security, ssl, certificate

I want to use self-signed certificate. So I try this:

```
$context = stream_context_create([
    'ssl' => [
        'verify_peer' => true,
        'allow_self_signed' => true,
        'peer_fingerprint' => [
            'sha1' => 'bddad63a826ff53f15ffd4f2339fe573fc01321d',
            'md5' => 'a7fb0783ffdab99a866ba31e5e15f2e7',
        ],
    ]
]);

file_get_contents(
    'https://example.com:8095',
    false,
    $context
);
```

But anyway I get

> "SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
>   error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate
>   verify failed'"

What should I do for fix this error? I don't want to turn `verify_peer` to false, because it's not secure. I just want to check certificate by fingerprint to ensure that I can trust this certificate.

Comment: Put your cert into: /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ and then run a `update-ca-certificates`. This obviously depends on your OS, but that's for debian.

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90450/adding-a-self-signed-certificate-to-the-trusted-list

Comment: I have self-compiled php with chroot directory, so I tried to put certificate both to /etc/ssl/certs and /usr/lib/certs and /usr/local/share/ca-certificates. But this method doesn't work. And if I try to run script from console without chroot, I haven't success. After your answer I installed on virtual machine Ubuntu 14.04 and try to do all from manual, but it's doesn't work too. If I run file_get_contents only with url, without stream context, it works always, even if certificate replaced to fake one. But if I leave my stream context, your method doesn't work too with the same error.